# how to extract value in queryset and convert to string

Tags: django, django-models

the output of my code is currently

`book_name = book.objects.values('book_name').filter(book_id=book_id)
 book_name =str(book_name[0])`

this code should give me 'Chronicles of Narnia '.
but it instead returns {'book_name': 'Chronicles of Narnia '}. how do i extract the value i need.

*note there will only be  1 value in this query every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), option `flat` will mean the returned results are single values:

```
book.objects.values('book_name')
.filter(book_id=book_id).values_list('book_name', flat=True)
# <QuerySet [book_name1, book_name2, book_name3, ...]>
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response my code now works